# Find the value of alpha on a pentagon.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, angle

Here is the question:

[image]

I have been trying this out for an hour, and I still dont know how to do it. Here's my progress: I'm stuck in this exact position and I dont know what to do next.

[image]

Can anyone help?

Comment: Angle-chasing, the sine rule and a scientific calculator should get you $\alpha=99^\circ$, and this is equivalent to the bisector dividing the side into the same angles already achieved on the diagonal by the line segment that's neither a side nor a diagonal. If you want help proving this, try labeling some points so future contributions can be less confusing than what I've just said.

Comment: I do not understand your progress. That's just the same diagram as the original. You need to tell us something beyond it. For example, if it is a pentagon with side as $1$, what is the distance from the vertex to the intersection point? Also your question is not well written. $\alpha$ could be any angle unless you tell more.

Comment: This is a nice problem! Often, this is not realized when posting such a problem. Unfortunately, because of missing context (good context can be provided by giving the source, level, own tries, some clear progress - even a minimal attempt, a better picture, etc.) this question did not get its merited echo. Please invest more time when publishing a question, it is in your own interest, since such supplementary considerations always help to understand - even to sensibly attack - the question. Questions may remain, but then this effort makes it easier to understand and compare solutions.

Comment: (I would have immediately voted for the question if it would have been presented to match to some modest extent the quality lines of the site.)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

$$\triangle BCG\implies\frac{BC}{\sin 45^\circ}=\frac{CG}{\sin63^\circ}\implies CG=a\frac{\sin63^\circ}{\sin45^\circ}$$

$$CG=a\frac{\sin45^\circ\cos18^\circ+\cos45^\circ\sin18^\circ}{\sin45^\circ}=a(\cos18^\circ+\sin18^\circ)\tag{1}$$

$$EC=2a\cos36^\circ=2a(\cos^2 18^\circ-\sin^2 18^\circ)\tag{2}$$

$$ (1) \land (2) \implies EG=EC-CG=a(2\cos^2 18^\circ-2\sin^2 18^\circ-\cos18^\circ-\sin18^\circ)\tag{3}$$

$$\triangle EGH\ (\angle EGH=\alpha) \implies \frac{EH}{\sin\alpha}=\frac{a}{2\sin\alpha}=\frac{EG}{\sin(180^\circ-36^\circ-\alpha)}=\frac{EG}{\sin(36^\circ+\alpha)}$$

$$\frac{a \sin(36^\circ+\alpha)}{2\sin\alpha}=EG=a(2\cos^2 18^\circ-2\sin^2 18^\circ-\cos18^\circ+\sin18^\circ)$$

$$\frac{\sin36^\circ\cos\alpha+\cos36^\circ\sin\alpha}{2\sin\alpha}=2\cos^2 18^\circ-2\sin^2 18^\circ-\cos18^\circ-\sin18^\circ$$

$$\sin18^\circ\cos18^\circ\cot\alpha+\frac12(\cos^2 18^\circ-\sin^2 18^\circ)=2\cos^2 18^\circ-2\sin^2 18^\circ-\cos18^\circ-\sin18^\circ$$

$$\cot\alpha=\frac{\frac32(\cos^2 18^\circ-\sin^2 18^\circ)-\cos18^\circ-\sin18^\circ}{\sin18^\circ\cos18^\circ}\tag{4}$$

$$\cot\alpha=\frac{3\cos36^\circ}{\sin36^\circ}-\frac{\cos18^\circ+\sin18^\circ}{\sin18^\circ\cos18^\circ}$$

$$\cot\alpha=3\cot36^\circ-\sec18^\circ-\csc18^\circ$$

For oblique angle $\alpha$ this gives the result:

$$\alpha=99^\circ$$

**EDIT** Let us prove that the answer is indeed $99^\circ$ and not some angle very close to it.

Introduce a constant:

$$t=\tan9^\circ$$

Obviously:

$$\tan(5\times 9^\circ)-1=0\tag{5}$$

This can be expanded so that the only items figuring in (5) are $t=\tan9^\circ$. After some straightforward but difficult work this leads to:

$$(-1 + t) (1 - 4 t - 14 t^2 - 4 t^3 + t^4) = 0$$

or (beacuse $t\ne1)$

$$1 - 4 t - 14 t^2 - 4 t^3 + t^4 = 0\tag{6}$$

Now, introduce the following replacements:

$$\cos18^\circ=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\ \ \sin18^\circ=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$$

...and replace it into (4). You get:

$$\cot\alpha=\frac{1-4t - 18t^2 -4 t^3 + 5 t^4}{4 t-4 t^3}$$

$$\cot\alpha=\frac{(1-4t - 14t^2 -4 t^3 + t^4)+ (-4t^2+4t^4)}{4 t-4 t^3}$$

The first item in the numerator is equal to zero according to (6) so the final result is:

$\cot\alpha=-t=-\tan 9^\circ$ which is only possible for $\alpha=99^\circ$, as stated initially.

Comment: How do you prove $3\cot36^\circ-\sec18^\circ-\csc18^\circ=\cot99^\circ$?

Comment: Good point, working on it

Comment: Linked: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4354239

Answer (score 1):

Let us put letters on the pentagon, let it be $ABCDE$, and let $F$ be the mid point of $DE$ as in the picture:

[image: math stackexchange regular pentagon 4352474]

Let $I$ be the incenter of $\Delta BEF$, which has the angles
with measures
$90^\circ=2\cdot 45^\circ$ in $F$,
$72^\circ=2\cdot 36^\circ$ in $E$, and
$18^\circ=2\cdot 9^\circ$ in $B$.

Then the angle $\widehat{BIC}$ is exterior for $\Delta EIB$, it measures $\hat E+\hat B=36^\circ+9^\circ=45^\circ$, so $I\in CD$ constructed above uniquely matches the point from the problem. So in $\Delta EIF$
$$
\widehat{EIF}
=
180^\circ
-
36^\circ
-
45^\circ
= 
99^\circ\ .
$$

$\square$

Comment: Nice! Please correct your last formula: it is not $BIC$ but $EIF$.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Mille grazie, it was too much copy+paste.